# Array as function parameter to mapping variable

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Suppose a function that accepts an array of addresses and looks like this:

```
function setVoters(address[] _inputAddresses) public ownerOnly {
    // [...]
}
```

the same contract that uses the aforementioned function has a variable defined as a mapping:

```
mapping(address => bool) voter;
```

Is looping over the array and pushing it to the mapping considered the best option when it comes to gas consumption/expenses or would it be better if the function accepts one address and does the iteration from a given UI via some JavaScript functionality?

**option a**:

```
function setVoters(address[] _inputAddresses) public ownerOnly {
    // [...]
    for (uint index = 0; index < _inputAddresses.length; index++) {
        voter[_inputAddresses[index]] = true;
    }
}
```

vs

**option b**:

```
function setVoter(address _inputAddress) public ownerOnly {
    // [...]
    voter[_inputAddress] = true;
}
```

JavaScript would look like this

```
// loop condition starts here
    await task.methods.setVoter(address[key]).send({
        from: accounts[0]
    });
// loop condition ends here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best in terms of gas efficiency is option a, calling a function takes quite a bit of gas, so you would pay less if you did it all in one big tx rather than many small ones.

Comment: So I've been told in a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/91xaew/stackoverflow_array_as_function_parameter_to/) as well. Although I'd like an answer with gas costs per option for visual reasons, your answer suits me for what I asked